# On successful HTTP Post record creation, I am not receiving the newly created record values back from the request. Why?

Tags: asp.net, webapi

I am expecting to see the newly created record values returned back in the resp variable.  When I look at it in debug the resp values are all NULLs.  The record is created from the http post and the newEntModel variable does have the data from new record.  Why is var resp values all nulls?  thanks

```
   // EntDataService.CS
    public async Task<EntModel> AddEnt(EntModel entModel)
    {
        var entJson =
           new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(entModel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        **var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/ents", entJson);**

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            **var resp** = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<EntModel>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
            return resp;
        }

        return null;
    }
    
    
    // API  that Creates the Record
    [HttpPost]

    public async Task<ActionResult<EntModel>> AddEnt([FromBody]EntModel entModel)
    {
        if (entModel == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var ent = _mapper.Map<Ent>(entModel);

        var newEnt = await _repository.AddEnt(ent);

        _repository.SaveAll();

        var newEntModel = _mapper.Map<EntModel>(newEnt);
        **return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetEnt),
             new { id = newEnt.EntId }, newEntModel);**

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified this line and the entModel was returned.
var resp = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });